# HP Docking connector pinout?

Tags: connector, hp-elitebook, docking

Ok, so I want to "build in" some hardware into my HP laptop (Elitebook 8560p)
Would like to build in a Logitech Unifying receiver and maybe some other stuff.
Was thinking about using the Docking connector, trying to find a USB connection. But I'v been google'ing for ever and cant find a Pin Out or diagram of the connector.

Anyone able to help out? :)

[image]

Comment: Images: https://imgur.com/a/PuXHy

Comment: HP does not publicly release this information.

Comment: Dropping this here in case it helps: check out post 15 by "jamescarpino" in [this thread](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/source-for-hp-male-expansion-port-1-connector.257661/post-1240952). It's not the pinout, but it's at least a starting point to help anyone who owns an oscilloscope feel like answering this is slightly less impossible

Comment: *to be specific, it's a JAE ([proprietary](http://www.heilind.com/products/jae/JAE_CTM/DD1_DD2_CTM_pdf.pdf)) 40-pin ["DD2" connector](http://web.archive.org/web/20160322002200/jae-connector.com/en/pdf/MB-0112-3E_DD2.pdf) (available [pretty](https://www.mouser.com/Connectors/I-O-Connectors/DD2-Series/_/N-1yrnl?P=1yz4pqy) [much](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/pluggable-connectors/443?s=3730&pv88=211651) [anywhere](https://www.alliedelec.com/board-level-connectors/board-mount-cable-connectors-headers/?n8739=40&searchWithin=DD2); though AFAICT, no knockoffs exist yet)